# How is the energy distributed over the harmonics of a standing wave? Does it follow an exponential decay law?

Tags: energy, waves

A string that gets plucked produces overtones or harmonics if I am not mistaken. The frequencies are given by:

$$ f_n = n \frac{nv}{2L} $$

The energy of a standing wave is given by:

$$ E_n = \mu \lambda_n \omega^2 A^2 $$

I was wondering how the energy gets distributed over the overtones.
According to the above energy formula the energy of a standing wave goes down for shorter wave lengths. This seems a bit counterintuitive. I would have expected that standing waves with more nodes had higher energy. Maybe I am misinterpreting the equation.

I would expect that when a string gets plucked a lot of harmonics gets produced. Just like in this image:
[image]

How does the energy get distributed over all the overtones?
Does it follow an exponential decay law, just like a boltzman factor? Or something completely else?

$$ e^{-E_n/kT} $$

Comment: it depends on how the string is plucked including impedance between the string the plectrum

Comment: @hyportnex And it changes as different overtones damp at different rates.

Comment: But in the most general case? Or is there nothing to be said about that. I would expect that there is a certain distribution of energies.